# Server UTC time and date.js getTimezoneOffset different

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, datejs

I have my code hosted on my local and on a server, and milliseconds since Epoch is behaving unexpectedly on my server.

I have `new Date("07/16/2018 10:17:48").getTime()` hardcoded, and on my local, result is 1531761468000, server: 1531736268000. Server is 7 hours behind.

I ran `date +%z`, local: -0700, server: -0700

I ran `date.getTimezoneOffset()`, local: 420 (converts to UTC-7), server: 0 (converts to UTC)

What may be the reason for this discrepancy? I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: What timezone is `07/16/2018 10:17:48`? Local? Server? Hololulu? Uganda?

Comment: That is a non-standard string so parsing is implementation dependent. Likely it’s being parsed as local and the 7 hours represents the difference in system time zones between your sever and client.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you run Node.js on the server. Please compare process.env for server and local.

```
console.log(process.env);
```

Consider process.env.TZ! Your node process will not use a call of date(1) but instead honor the environment. If this is indeed the reason, you could fix it by adjusting the actual environment (via supervisor or whatever you use to start your process) or by changing it just after start inside your script.

This post should be helpful by showing you some options you have to control the environment of your server process: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/heres-how-you-can-actually-use-node-environment-variables-8fdf98f53a0a

Comment: Oh thanks! My process.env for server is undefined. I'm not too experienced; is this normal?

Comment: This can be normal. You have a lot of options to set the environment for your node process. I edited my original answer to point you to a helpful guide.